# Для чего нужны зависимости "peerDependencies"?

Tags: npm, package, зависимости

Я делаю расширение класса, который в свою очередь является расширением другого. Пусть это будут `Base` и `Extension`.
Мой проект зависит от пакета, содержащего `Extension` имеющего в `peerDependencies` пакет с классом `Base`.
Похоже, что не установив в своём проекте зависимость, указанную там, я не могу собрать его в WebPack.
Объясните, в каких случаях используется `peerDependencies`, почему зависимость не указать, например, в `dev`? Зачем, если зависимость уже имеется, мне нужно создавать новую?

Answer (score 0):

В devDependencies указываются зависимости для программистов, то есть нужные  непосредственно для изменения кода или ресурсов. В частности, сюда входят все пакеты, необходимые для компиляции кода.

В dependencies указываются зависимости, обязательные для непосредственно функционирования пакета.

Бывает, разные плагины требуют разные версии одного пакета. Такие пакеты добавляются в peerDependencies. Как правило, npm сам добавляет пакеты с нужными версиями, когда находит разные версии среди вторичных зависимостей или цикличные зависимости. Вручную добавлять их туда бессмысленно. Да и кому захочется ковыряться в чужих кодах.

[Источник](https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/)

Comment: Возможно я глупенький, но что-то я ничего не понял. 1) Если разные плагины требуют разные версии, они ж будут принципиально неработоспособны друг с другом, не? Какой тогда смысл отцеплять зависимости? 2) Цикличные зависимости — это ж косяк разработчиков, который нужно исправлять, не? 3) По ссылке написано «even if plugins did put down their host package as a dependency, the downloaded copy would never be used» и я совершенно не понял почему

Comment: 1) Плагины требуют разные версии пакета, но у самих плагинов нет необходимости взаимодействовать друг с другом, но при этом ваша программа может взаимодействовать с каждым плагином как по отдельности так и вместе. При этом у вас нет необходимости задумываться о внутреннем строении чужих модулей, вы просто их используете и всё. 2) циклические зависимости - в случаях с дистрибутивами линукса - это косяк коммитера, но в случае с npm там каждый автор модуля сам себе коммитер и надзора никакого нет.

Comment: По третьему, вы немного вырвали из контекста. Там речь идет о плагинах. В качестве примера, рассматривают grunt. У гранта есть много много плагинов. В модулях этих плагинов нигде не пишется зависимость от grunt. А если автор плагина включит определённую версию grunt как зависимость к плагину, прописанная версия grunt загрузится в node_modules, но в своём проекте вы будете использовать версию grunt, которую прописали вы, а не автор плагина, и тогда дополнительная копия grunt будет просто лишней и никогда не будет использоваться.

Comment: 1) Всё равно не понимаю, я как пользователь плагинов буду должен связать их друг с другом в каком-то одном хост-объекте (иначе зачем мне плагины вообще?), и тогда один из плагинов (тот, для которого я использовал несовместимую версию хост-объекта) обязательно сломается. 2) Ну так это не проблема npm, пусть разработчики сами разбираются с тем что они наломали, при чём тут peer dependencies? 3) Опять же вопрос зависимостей сводится к пункту 1: если я буду использовать неправильную версию grunt, плагин просто сломается, и как тут peer dependencies поможет?

Comment: Смотрите, предположим, вы делаете сайтик. Подключаете к нему два модуля: модуль прогноза погоды и модуль курсов валют. Модуль прогноза погоды закачивает прогноз используя request версии 1.9.x. А модуль курсов валют использует для запросов данных request версии 2.0. Сами по себе версии request несовместимы друг с другом так как имеют совершенно разный API. Но  для вас важно не то, какую версию request использует каждый плагин (пока нет известных уязвимостей), важно лишь просто чтобы они работали, а если не будут работать, то просто сменить их на что-то другое.

Comment: В таком случае оба модуля должны содержать в своих dependencies нужные им версии request, иначе они банально будут сломаны. Всё равно не понимаю, при чём тут peer dependencies

Comment: Так npm и обеспечивает работу разных модулей. И получается, что при установке будут закачены обе версии request. При этом, вы  для своих запросов можете использовать третью версию request. И всё равно всё это вместе будет работать. peerDependency просто помогает разрулить этот момент, что когда вы будете устанавливать свой модуль на сервере, npm сразу закачает все необходимые версии модуля request.

Comment: Что мешает закачать несколько версий с помощью обычных dependencies без всяких peer? В том же Rust это отлично работает и никакого peer в нём нету, например

Comment: С rust там компиляция кода происходит в момент билда. А в nodejs компилируются только некоторые модули, написанные на C и на C++. Но большинство модулей написаны на JS и все проблемы с зависимостями всплывают только во время запуска.

Comment: К сожалению, это не добавило мне ни капельки понимания

Comment: Ну еще для статистики NPM на момент 16 марта 2020г хостит `1.3 million packages and 75 billion downloads a month`, Для сравнения crates `4 955 688 669 downloads 51 209 crates in stock` (здесь количество загрузок всего со дня основания crates)